# Meta wrongly suspends a Canadian Consumer's account. What are Canadians' causes of action?

Tags: contract-law, california

#### Fact Pattern for Consumer who lives in Canada, and is Canadian citizen.

I forgo naming territories and provinces, because this fact pattern has happened to Canadians across provinces. But Consumer is not American citizen, and is not connected to California. Premise that Consumer has done nothing wrong, Consumer has not paid any money to Meta, and Consumer has a contract with Meta.<sup>⓵</sup>

Meta suspended Consumer's Facebook or Instagram account [for no reason at all, or for a wrong reason](https://old.reddit.com/r/facebookdisabledme). Consumer emailed Meta Inc. multiple times, and sent multiple letters by registered mail. Consumer can prove registered letter's delivery to, and receipt by, Meta Inc. But Meta never responded to Consumer.

## Questions

1. What jurisdiction or court must Consumer file her Claim against Meta Inc.? Can Consumer sue in her Canadian province or territory?
2. What are Consumer's causes of action?
3. I am iffy about [Andrew Oh-Willeke's answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/84313), as he doesn't cite the following paragraph from [Instagram's Help Center revised 26 July 2022](https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870).

> ##### How We Will Handle Disputes.
>
> If you are a consumer, the laws of the country in which you reside will apply to any claim, cause of action, or dispute you have against us that arises out of or relates to these Terms ("claim"), and you may resolve your claim in any competent court in that country that has jurisdiction over the claim. In all other cases, you agree that the claim must be resolved exclusively in the U.S. District Court for the Northern District of California or a state court located in San Mateo County, that you submit to the personal jurisdiction of either of these courts for the purpose of litigating any such claim, and that the laws of the State of California will govern these Terms and any claim, without regard to conflict of law provisions. Without prejudice to the foregoing, you agree that, in its sole discretion, Meta Platforms Inc. may also bring any claim we have against you related to efforts to abuse, interfere, or engage with our products in unauthorized ways in the country in which you reside that has jurisdiction over the claim.

#### <sup>⓵</sup> Postulate that  Consumer has a contract with Meta Inc.

[Clifton Gilley](https://www.gartner.com/analyst/89180/Clifton-Gilley) has  J.D. from Seattle University School of Law, cum laude. On [Quora](https://www.quora.com/With-no-apparent-consideration-from-the-user-how-can-the-user-service-agreement-for-a-site-like-Facebook-be-a-legally-binding-contract/answer/Cliff-G-13), Gilley wrote

> Consideration is merely "something of value"; it need not be money, though many think that is so. Facebook is offering you usage of their service, which they consider "something of value" in exchange for your agreement to the terms of service. The user agrees to grant Facebook license to use their content in certain ways, and that license is also "something of value." That is technically sufficient to create a binding contract.
>
> Facebook collects and uses a **massive** amount of user-generated data on a daily basis to sell advertising and for other purposes; there is certainly valuable consideration being given by the user here.

[Jennifer Ellis](https://jlellis.net/detailed-biography/) has JD from Widener University School of Law in Delaware. On [Quora](https://www.quora.com/With-no-apparent-consideration-from-the-user-how-can-the-user-service-agreement-for-a-site-like-Facebook-be-a-legally-binding-contract/answer/Jennifer-Ellis), Ellis wrote

> There is mutual consideration. Facebook allows people to use its site. That is the thing of value that the user is getting. Facebook benefits from people using its site. That is the value Facebook is getting.

Comment: "presume that Consumer has a contract with Meta"/"What are Consumer's causes of action?": it depends on the terms of the contract, now, doesn't it?  What are the terms?

Comment: @phoog ["We can disable your account at any moment fro any breach of your obligations"](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php) under 4.2

Comment: @Trish when I click that link, I get the Irish terms of service, presumably because I am in Europe.  It does not contain the clause that you quote.  It may be difficult for people outside of Canada to find the terms of service that apply in Canada.

Comment: @phoog possible, it's rather tricky... I tried to summarize 4.2, which is the termination policy.

Comment: @Trish That quotation is not relevant. Consumer never breached  Consumer's obligations, which is presumed as fact here.

Comment: @asts [citation needed]

Comment: @Trish What do you mean by "[citation needed]"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most user complaints against Meta are [subject to binding arbitration](https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870) under the applicable terms of service (which is the principal contract between a user and Meta) and cannot be litigated in the court system. The example of a dispute in the question would not generally fall within the exceptions to the arbitration clause. It states, in part:

> The Instagram Service is one of the Meta Products, provided to you by
> Meta Platforms, Inc. These Terms of Use therefore constitute an
> agreement between you and Meta Platforms, Inc.
>
> ARBITRATION NOTICE: YOU AGREE THAT DISPUTES BETWEEN YOU AND US WILL BE
> RESOLVED BY BINDING, INDIVIDUAL ARBITRATION AND YOU WAIVE YOUR RIGHT
> TO PARTICIPATE IN A CLASS ACTION LAWSUIT OR CLASS-WIDE ARBITRATION. WE
> EXPLAIN SOME EXCEPTIONS AND HOW YOU CAN OPT OUT OF ARBITRATION BELOW. . . .
>
> How We Will Handle Disputes.
>
> Except as provided below, you and we agree that any cause of action,
> legal claim, or dispute between you and us arising out of or related
> to these Terms or Instagram ("claim(s)") must be resolved by
> arbitration on an individual basis. Class actions and class
> arbitrations are not permitted; you and we may bring a claim only on
> your own behalf and cannot seek relief that would affect other
> Instagram users. If there is a final judicial determination that any
> particular claim (or a request for particular relief) cannot be
> arbitrated in accordance with this provision's limitations, then only
> that claim (or only that request for relief) may be brought in court.
> All other claims (or requests for relief) remain subject to this
> provision.
>
> Instead of using arbitration, you or we can bring claims in your local
> "small claims" court, if the rules of that court will allow it. If you
> don't bring your claims in small claims court (or if you or we appeal
> a small claims court judgment to a court of general jurisdiction),
> then the claims must be resolved by binding, individual arbitration.
> The American Arbitration Association will administer all arbitrations
> under its Consumer Arbitration Rules. You and we expressly waive a
> trial by jury.
>
> The following claims don't have to be arbitrated and may be brought in
> court: disputes related to intellectual property (like copyrights and
> trademarks), violations of our Platform Policy, or efforts to
> interfere with the Service or engage with the Service in unauthorized
> ways (for example, automated ways). In addition, issues relating to
> the scope and enforceability of the arbitration provision are for a
> court to decide.
>
> This arbitration provision is governed by the Federal Arbitration Act.
>
> You can opt out of this provision within 30 days of the date that you
> agreed to these Terms. To opt out, you must send your name, residence
> address, username, email address or phone number you use for your
> Instagram account, and a clear statement that you want to opt out of
> this arbitration agreement, and you must send them here: Meta
> Platforms, Inc. ATTN: Instagram Arbitration Opt-out, 1601 Willow Rd.,
> Menlo Park, CA 94025.
>
> Before you commence arbitration of a claim, you must provide us with a
> written Notice of Dispute that includes your name, residence address,
> username, email address or phone number you use for your Instagram
> account, a detailed description of the dispute, and the relief you
> seek. Any Notice of Dispute you send to us should be mailed to Meta
> Platforms, Inc., ATTN: Instagram Arbitration Filing, 1601 Willow Rd.
> Menlo Park, CA 94025. Before we commence arbitration, we will send you
> a Notice of Dispute to the email address you use with your Instagram
> account, or other appropriate means. If we are unable to resolve a
> dispute within thirty (30) days after the Notice of Dispute is
> received, you or we may commence arbitration.
>
> We will pay all arbitration filing fees, administration and hearing
> costs, and arbitrator fees for any arbitration we bring or if your
> claims seek less than $75,000 and you timely provided us with a Notice
> of Dispute. For all other claims, the costs and fees of arbitration
> shall be allocated in accordance with the arbitration provider's
> rules, including rules regarding frivolous or improper claims.
>
> For any claim that is not arbitrated or resolved in small claims
> court, you agree that it will be resolved exclusively in the U.S.
> District Court for the Northern District of California or a state
> court located in San Mateo County. You also agree to submit to the
> personal jurisdiction of either of these courts for the purpose of
> litigating any such claim.
>
> The laws of the State of California, to the extent not preempted by or
> inconsistent with federal law, will govern these Terms and any claim,
> without regard to conflict of law provisions.

While I haven't checked every single Meta service, I would strongly suspect that the Terms of Service for all of their online offerings have very similar provisions to this one.

Comment: When I click that link, I get the Irish terms of service, presumably because I am in Europe.  A quick scan didn't find anything about binding arbitration.  It may be difficult for people outside of Canada to find the terms of service that apply in Canada.

Comment: @phoog VPNs might help.

Comment: How does this answer my question at all? If Meta keeps ignoring Consumer, then how does Consumer even start the arbitration against Meta?

Comment: @asts It is spelled out with even an address to write to, what more do you want?

Comment: What about the section under **"How We Will Handle Disputes."**?
"If you are a consumer, the laws of the country in which you reside will apply to any claim, cause of action, or dispute you have against us that arises out of or relates to these Terms ("claim"), and you may resolve your claim in any competent court in that country that has jurisdiction over the claim. In all other cases, you agree that the claim must be resolved exclusively in the U.S. District Court for the Northern District of California or a state court located in San Mateo County,

Comment: that you submit to the personal jurisdiction of either of these courts for the purpose of litigating any such claim, and that the laws of the State of California will govern these Terms and any claim, without regard to conflict of law provisions. Without prejudice to the foregoing, you agree that, in its sole discretion, Meta Platforms Inc. may also bring any claim we have against you related to efforts to abuse, interfere, or engage with our products in unauthorized ways in the country in which you reside that has jurisdiction over the claim."

Comment: @asts This section you quote is definitely different that what I see, probably due to a geolocated difference in content. Where I am located, the parallel language after  **How We Will Handle Disputes** states immediately after that: "Except as provided below, you and we agree that any cause of action, legal claim, or dispute between you and us arising out of or related to these Terms or Instagram ("claim(s)") must be resolved by arbitration on an individual basis. . . ." It does not have the language that you quote, which is probably what it uses to all places not subject to the FAA.